# In Ant Design "Rules" in the Form.Items of Form component are not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd, antform

### I am trying to use the rules in the Form. Items but because of some  reason it is not supporting

NOTE: The number is not supporting but that is not an issue rules feature is not supporting at all.
NOTE: I think because it is rendering a lot that is why rules are not getting applied.

### Any help to solve the issue will be great.

- Here is a form component Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Button } from 'antd';
import { component as Template } from '@ivoyant/component-template';

class InputFormComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        formData: {},
    };

    enableInputFocus = (State, Props) => {
        const empty = {};

        const isObject = x => Object(x) === x;

        const diff1 = (left = {}, right = {}, rel = 'left') =>
            Object.entries(left)
                .map(([k, v]) =>
                    isObject(v) && isObject(right[k])
                        ? [k, diff1(v, right[k], rel)]
                        : right[k] !== v
                        ? [k, { [rel]: v }]
                        : [k, empty]
                )
                .reduce(
                    (acc, [k, v]) => (v === empty ? acc : { ...acc, [k]: v }),
                    empty
                );

        const merge = (left = {}, right = {}) =>
            Object.entries(right).reduce(
                (acc, [k, v]) =>
                    isObject(v) && isObject(left[k])
                        ? { ...acc, [k]: merge(left[k], v) }
                        : { ...acc, [k]: v },
                left
            );

        const diff = (x = {}, y = {}) =>
            merge(diff1(x, y, 'left'), diff1(y, x, 'right'));

        const key = Object.keys(diff(State, Props))[0];

        for (const property in Props) {
            if (key == property) {
                Props[property].focus = true;
            } else {
                Props[property].focus = false;
            }
        }

        return Props;
    };

    onFinish = values => {
        const { formData } = this.state;

        global.console.log('Success: formData :', formData);
        
    };

    getDataFromFormItem = values => {
        const { formData } = this.state;
        const updatedValues = this.enableInputFocus(formData, values);

        this.setState({ formData: { ...formData, ...updatedValues } });
    };

    onFinishFailed = errorInfo => {
        global.console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
    };

    render() {
        const { children, properties } = this.props;
        const {
            submitButtonText,
            formClassName,
            submitButtonClassNmae,
        } = properties;
        const { formData } = this.state;

        const childComponent = React.Children.map(children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                sendDataToForm: this.getDataFromFormItem,
                updateFormData: this.updateFormData,
                values: { ...formData },
            });
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <Form
                    className={formClassName && formClassName}
                    onFinish={this.onFinish}
                    onFinishFailed={this.onFinishFailed}
                >
                    {childComponent}

                    <Form.Item>
                        <Button
                            type="primary"
                            htmlType="submit"
                            className={
                                submitButtonClassNmae && submitButtonClassNmae
                            }
                        >
                            {submitButtonText && submitButtonText}
                        </Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default InputFormComponent;
```

- Below is the code for the Input field, which is a totally different component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Form } from 'antd';

class InputComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        formItemData: {},
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const { values } = this.props;
        for (const property in values) {
            if (values[property].focus === true) {
                this[property] && this[property].focus();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Bellow code is use when we are not passing input component as a direct child of Form component
         */
        if (this.props.parentProps)
            for (const property in this.props.parentProps.values) {
                if (this.props.parentProps.values[property].focus === true) {
                    this[property] && this[property].focus();
                }
            }

        /**
         * In Bellow code true condition is exected when we are not passing input component as a direct child of Form component
         */
        this.props.parentProps
            ? this.setState({
                  formItemData: { ...values, ...this.props.parentProps.values },
              })
            : this.setState({ formItemData: { ...values } });
    }

    handleOnChange = event => {
        const { formItemData } = this.state;
        const { id, value } = event.target;

        const ID = id;
        const object = {};

        object[ID] = {
            VALUE: value,
            focus: false,
        };

        this.setState(
            {
                formItemData: { ...formItemData, ...object },
            },
            () => {
                this.props.sendDataToForm &&
                    this.props.sendDataToForm(this.state.formItemData);
                /**
                 * Bellow code is use when we are not passing input component as a direct child of Form component
                 */
                this.props.parentProps &&
                    this.props.parentProps.sendDataToForm &&
                    this.props.parentProps.sendDataToForm(
                        this.state.formItemData
                    );
            }
        );
    };

    render() {
        const { id, className } = this.props.properties;
        const { values, children } = this.props;
        const { formItemData } = this.state;

        const { inputFieldsConfiguration } = this.props.properties;

        const childComponent = React.Children.map(children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                parentProps: { ...this.props },
            });
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={className && className}>
                    {inputFieldsConfiguration &&
                        // eslint-disable-next-line complexity
                        inputFieldsConfiguration.map(data => {
                            return (
                                <div
                                    className={data.itemAndInputClassName}
                                    key={data.id && data.id}
                                >
                                    <div className={data.labalClassName}>
                                        {data.label && data.label}
                                    </div>
                                    <Form.Item
                                        key={data.id}
                                        hasFeedback
                                        name={data.id}
                                        help={data.help && data.help}
                                        className={
                                            data.formItemClassName &&
                                            data.formItemClassName
                                        }
                                        rules={[
                                            {
                                                type: "url",
                                             }
                                        ]}
                                    >
                                        <Input
                                            ref={input => {
                                                this[data.id] = input;
                                            }}
                                            placeholder={
                                                data.placeholder &&
                                                data.placeholder
                                            }
                                            id={data.id && data.id}
                                            disabled ={data.disabled && data.disabled }
                                            value={
                                                formItemData &&
                                                formItemData[data.id] &&
                                                formItemData[data.id].ID === ''
                                                    ? values &&
                                                      values[data.id] &&
                                                      values[data.id].VALUE
                                                    : formItemData &&
                                                      formItemData[data.id] &&
                                                      formItemData[data.id]
                                                          .VALUE
                                            }
                                            className={
                                                data.inputItemClassName &&
                                                data.inputItemClassName
                                            }
                                            onChange={e =>
                                                this.handleOnChange(e)
                                            }
                                        />
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                </div>
                {childComponent}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default InputComponent;
```